# React/ES6 Onscroll function not triggering in Y direction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

**Reference** [image of Scroll bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59LLe.png)

I have created a web application in which I need value of scrollTop. Changing the overflow property I got to know that Y-axis scrolling is occur from ***index.js*** file. Scroll bar in X-axis occur from ***SUB COMPONENT*** created by me  and its parent is rendered in ***App.js***.

I have created scroll event handler in ***index.js***. which is getting triggered only for X-axis scrolling which is occuring from sub component but not triggering for Y-axis scrolling.

Can anyone help me out here please to get scrollTop value.

Folder Structure:


***index.js***  (Y-axis scroll bar is formed due to this javascript file, I need scrollTop value by scrolling this, created scroll event here which is not triggering for this)
***App.js***

***components folder***

          |
          |
          ***component.js***
          ***sub component folder***
                    |
                    |
                    ***subComponent.js*** (X-axis scroll bar is formed due to this javascript file, scroll event handler created in ***index.js*** is triggered from this)
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you'll need to attach an event listener to the sub-component; it will have its own scroll offsets.

Comment: Probably you misunderstood what I have written, event listener is in index.js and not triggering there (which is required for me), but triggering for scrolling in sub-component.